# What is $J_0$ if $J_k =(1+a_k)J_{k+1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Given a sequence $\{J_k\}_{k=0}^\infty$ that is defined recursively by the formula $J_k =(1+a_k)J_{k+1}$ where $\{a_k\}_{k=0}^\infty$ is another sequence of positive real numbers and $J_k \to 1$ as $k \to \infty$, I [want to show](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2296206/404320) that:

$$ J_0 = \sum_{m = 0}^\infty \  \sum_{j_1\lt...\lt j_m} \prod_{p=1}^m  a_{j_p}$$

Kindly help.

Comment: $J_0$ is your 0.th element in the sequenz $\{J_k\}_{k=0}^\infty$ and should be defined somewhere?

Comment: @MundronSchmidt $J_0$ is defined by the given recursive formula like all the other terms are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't follow from the information given. I can arbitrarily decide that $J_5 = 17$ and come up with values for all other $J_k$ that are consistent with this:
\begin{align}
  J_0 &= 17(1+a_0)(1+a_1)(1+a_2)(1+a_3)(1+a_4) \\
  J_1 &= 17(1+a_1)(1+a_2)(1+a_3)(1+a_4) \\
  J_2 &= 17(1+a_2)(1+a_3)(1+a_4)\\
  J_3 &= 17(1+a_3)(1+a_4) \\
  J_4 &= 17(1+a_4) \\
  J_5 &= 17 \\
  J_6 &= \frac{17}{1+a_5} \\
  J_7 &= \frac{17}{(1+a_5)(1+a_6)} \\
  J_8 &= \frac{17}{(1+a_5)(1+a_6)(1+a_7)} 
\end{align}
and so  on.

However, assuming that the infinite product $$\prod_{n=0}^\infty (1 + a_n)$$ converges, if we want $J_k \to 1$ as $k \to \infty$, then we must set $J_0$ equal to this product. (Because, in general, we have $J_0 = J_k \prod_{n=0}^{k-1} (1+a_n)$.)

If we expand the product $\prod_{n=0}^\infty (1 + a_n)$, we get a term for every possible way to choose $a_{j_1}, a_{j_2}, \dots, a_{j_m}$ from some $(j_1)^{\text{th}}, (j_2)^{\text{th}}, \dots, (j_m)^{\text{th}}$ factors, and $1$ from all the other factors, which we can write as:
$$\prod_{n=0}^\infty (1 + a_n) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{j_1 < j_2 < \dots < j_m} \prod_{p=1}^m a_{j_p}.$$
This is vaguely reminiscent of the form you want for $J_0$.

In my opinion, a better way to understand this expansion is that it is $$\prod_{n=0}^\infty (1 + a_n) = \sum_{S \subset \mathbb N} \prod_{j \in S} a_j$$
where the set $S$ ranges over all subsets of $\mathbb N$ and the product $\prod_{j \in S} a_j$ corresponds to the term in the expansion of $\prod_{n=0}^\infty (1 + a_n)$ where we pick the $a_j$ from the $j^{\text{th}}$ factor if $j \in S$ and pick the $1$ from the $j^{\text{th}}$ factor if $j \notin S$.

We may assume $S$ is finite, because all products $\prod_{j \in S} a_j$ where $S$ is infinite should be $0$ if the infinite product for $J_0$ converges. This lets us rewrite $$\sum_{S \subset \mathbb N} \prod_{j \in S} a_j = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{\substack{S \subset \mathbb N \\ |S|=m}} \prod_{j \in S} a_j = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{j_1 < j_2 < \dots < j_m} \prod_{p=1}^m a_{j_p}$$ by summing over all possible sets $S = \{j_1, j_2, \dots, j_m\}$, for all finite sizes $m$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit more on your last point? How do you guess each of the pieces in the expansion of the infinite product? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've added some more details. (And fixed a typo in what I had originally written: the inequality $j_1 < j_2 < \dots < j_m$ should be strict, because we never get a term such as $a_0^2 a_1 a_4$ in the expansion of the product.)